# Inheriting Forms from the Object Repository

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I am using Delphi 10.3.2 Rio Pro.  I have created a framework of several Firemonkey forms which inherit from a base form and added them all to the Object Repository.  When I create a new form inheriting from one of theses forms, the inheriting form and two new ones base on it are added to my project.  In order to compile the project, I will need to add the base form also.  I have several questions.

1. Is there a way to prevent the inheriting (and base) forms from being added to my project and have the project successfully compile?
2. Why are two new forms being created?  How do I stop this so that only one is created?

Comment: If you inherit from them, they have to be added to your project. How else would the descendant be created if the ancestor isn't there? You can't descend from a base form unless that base form is there to descend from in the first place.

Comment: @KenWhite I know they have to be available for inheritance, but why does the form HAVE to be a part of the project?  Why can it not be in a package?

Comment: A package is a glorified Dll, so your base form can't be in it if you want to compile to a stand-alone app.

Comment: If you want to run code, it needs to be loaded somewhere

Comment: Because in order for the IDE to work with it, it has to be in the same project as the forms that descend from it, because the IDE has to open the ancestor before it can load the descendant. If it's not in the project, it's not available at the time the descendant is being loaded.

Comment: @KenWhite I have apparently misunderstood how the Object Repository is designed to work.  I thought that if Delphi contains the form in the Repository, it knows where the form is located and will able to link it into the executable, much the same as it does for items you select from the Component Palette which have been installed with packages.  Thanks for the clarification.